# How do I write in a single query two different sum queries with different conditions?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a MySQL datatable `items` as below:

```
+----+-------+----------+----------+
| id | value | discount |   type   |
+----+-------+----------+----------+
|  1 |    20 |        1 | hardware |
|  2 |    40 |        0 | hardware |
|  3 |    60 |        1 | software |
|  4 |    30 |        1 | software |
+----+-------+----------+----------+
```

When `discount` is 1, this means that effectively the `value` is ZERO.

I want to get back the following results

```
+----------+----+
| software |  0 |
| hardware | 40 |
+----------+----+
```

I know how to do this in multiple queries.

```
SELECT type, SUM(value) from items where discount != 1 group by type
```

which gives me just

```
+----------+----+
| hardware | 40 |
+----------+----+
```

and then

```
SELECT type, 0 from items where discount = 1 group by type
```

which gives me

```
+----------+----+
| software |  0 |
| hardware |  0 |
+----------+----+
```

then i need to join these two tables to get the final result.

My question is :

is there a way I can accomplish the same result with just 1 query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
SELECT type, SUM(if(discount =1, 0,value)) from items group by type
```